# Is there any Ionic/Cordova plugin to read SMS without need permission of APP?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sms, cordova-plugins

Recently, Google has changed policy for reading SMS by mobile APP. so, now they are not allowing to give the permission of READ_SMS.

There is a way to read SMS in Native Android using SMS Retriever API [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview). but, I can't see any plugin to read SMS by APP which is developed in Ionic/Cordova.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ionic-native-sms-retriever-plugin-master](https://github.com/hanatharesh2712/ionic-native-sms-retriever-plugin-master) - it's hot off the presses and I haven't tried it, but this implements the SMS Retriever API in a Cordova plugin. Of course you also need the corresponding [server implementation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify).