# Cordova Android app crashes on Android P due to RECEIVE_SMS permission denial

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions, crash

I have a Cordova Android app which works fine on earlier versions of Android OS, but app starts to crash on Android P (9.0), and I am getting the following logs while app launches:

```
Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x19000010 (has extras) } to com.example.myapp requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone
```

My app is retrieving SMS for OTP autocomplete and i already added RECEIVE_SMS  permission to config file.

It seems we have to migrate to the SMS Retrieval API which is described in [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303), but in this case we need a cordova plugin to do so.

I will appreciate if anyone can guide how to fix this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135681/777265

Comment: This plugins seems will fix the issue, but it requires a server-side changes. I implement that and see. Thanks anyways.

Comment: > `it requires a server-side changes`. You can thank Google for that.

Comment: :), Yes, thank you Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this cordova plugin - https://github.com/diegosiao/cordova-plugin-android-sms-retriever
This might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below cordova plugin for permission.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

Comment: Thanks bro, but the idea is to apply the same feature without using the permission.